# How can I setup a git repository to be a collection of 3 different repositories?

Tags: git

I would like to have a git repository for my wordpress plugins directory and I would like it to pull from each plugins own repository and be easy to update when a plugin is updated. How is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Possibly submodules: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule

Answer (score 2):

[Submodules](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) would be the way to go.

Here is a [tutorial](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitSubmoduleTutorial) to get you started.